# How to extract information from ODP accurately?

Tags: python, search-engine

I am building a search engine in python.

I have heard that Google fetches the description of pages from the ODP ([Open Directory Project](http://dmoz.org)) in case Google can't figure out the description using the meta data from the page... I wanted to do something similar.

ODP is an online directory from Mozilla which has descriptions of pages on the net, so I wanted to fetch the descriptions for my search results from the ODP. How do I get the accurate description of a particular url from ODP, and return the python type "None" if I couldn't find it (Which means ODP has no idea what page i am looking for)?

PS. there is a url called http://dmoz.org/search?q=Your+Search+Params but I dont know how to extract information from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use ODP data, you'd [download the RDF data dump](http://rdf.dmoz.org/). RDF is a XML format; you'd index that dump to map urls to descriptions; I'd use a SQL database for this.

Note that URLs can be present in multiple locations in the dump. Stack Overflow is listed at twice, for example. Google uses the text from [this entry](http://www.dmoz.org/Reference/Ask_an_Expert/Computers_and_Technology/) as the site description, Bing uses [this one instead](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Resources/Chats_and_Forums/).

The data dump is of course rather large. Use sensible tools such as the ElementTree [`iterparse()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) to parse the data set iteratively as you add entries to your database. You really only need to look for the `<ExternalPage>` elements, taking the `<d:Title>` and `<d:Description>` entries underneath.

Using `lxml` (a faster and more complete ElementTree implementation) that'd look like:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
import gzip
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/database')

# create table
with conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS odp_urls 
        (url text primary key, title text, description text)''')

count = 0
nsmap = {'d': 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.0/'}
with gzip.open('content.rdf.u8.gz', 'rb') as content, conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    for event, element in ET.iterparse(content, tag='{http://dmoz.org/rdf/}ExternalPage'):
        url = element.attrib['about']
        title = element.xpath('d:Title/text()', namespaces=nsmap)
        description = element.xpath('d:Description/text()', namespaces=nsmap)
        title, description = title and title[0] or '', description and description[0] or ''

        # no longer need this, remove from memory again, as well as any preceding siblings
        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]

        cursor.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO odp_urls VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
            (url, title, description))
        count += 1
        if count % 1000 == 0:
            print 'Processed {} items'.format(count)
```

Comment: do you mean google has also downloaded the rdf dump? if so, do i have to sit and download it multiple times for updates? @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @user2335164: You download it periodically, yes. The most recent dump was created on the 28th of April.

Comment: thanks a lot! Can you please tell me how to use the downloaded rdf dump from python.. if you do, i'll accept your answer @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @user2335164 And after downloading it you can use [this parser](https://github.com/kremso/dmoz-parser) for further processing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters which download should i choose in the link you provided in your answer?

Comment: @user2335164: http://rdf.dmoz.org/rdf/content.rdf.u8.gz contains the data you are interested in.

Comment: thankyou!!! just comfirming, after i download the package, will there be a python accessible XML file in there?

Comment: @user2335164: It's a gzipped file, which the `gzip` should be able to handle. I whipped up an example script for you.

Comment: This github seems to allow for direct dmoz to mysql https://github.com/JoKnopp/dmoz2db