# lxml and fast_iter eating all the memory

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I want to parse a 1.6 GB XML file with Python (2.7.2) using lxml (3.2.0) on OS X (10.8.2). Because I had already read about potential issues with memory consumption, I already use [fast_iter](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/) in it, but after the main loop, it eats up about 8 GB RAM, even it doesn't keep any data from the actual XML file.

```
from lxml import etree

def fast_iter(context, func, *args, **kwargs):
    # http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/
    # Author: Liza Daly
    for event, elem in context:
        func(elem, *args, **kwargs)
        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]
    del context

def process_element(elem):
    pass

context = etree.iterparse("sachsen-latest.osm", tag="node", events=("end", ))
fast_iter(context, process_element)
```

I don't get, why there is such a massive leakage, because the element and the whole context is being deleted in `fast_iter()` and at the moment I don't even process the XML data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Parsing ODP data (using [an older answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355421/how-to-extract-information-from-odp-accurately/16355498#16355498)) with this method works fine for me; I see no memory increase beyond about 9MB real, 21.3 virtual memory.

Comment: After parsing more than 3.2 million entries a XML char ref error is encountered, but my `import gc; len(gc.get_objects())` test shows hardly any change in tracked objects, so I don't see any leak here myself.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the behavior of `etree.iterparse()`. You would think it only uses memory for each `node` element, but it turns out it still keeps all the other elements in memory. Since you don't clear them, memory ends up blowing up later on, specially when parsing .osm (OpenStreetMaps) files and looking for nodes, but more on that later.

The solution I found was not to catch `node` tags but catch all tags:

```
context = etree.iterparse(open(filename,'r'),events=('end',))
```

And then clear all the tags, but only parse the ones you are interested in:

```
for (event,elem) in progress.bar(context):
    if elem.tag == 'node':
        # do things here

    elem.clear()
    while elem.getprevious() is not None:
        del elem.getparent()[0]
del context
```

Do keep in mind that it may delete other elements that you are interested in, so make sure to add more ifs where needed. For example (And this is .osm specific) `tags` nested from `nodes`

```
if elem.tag == 'tag':
    continue
if elem.tag == 'node':
    for tag in elem.iterchildren():
        # do stuff
```

The reason why memory was blowing up later is pretty interesting, .osm files are [organized](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) in a way that `nodes` come first, then `ways` then `relations`. So your code does fine with nodes at the beginning, then memory gets filled as `etree` goes through the rest of the elements.