# best way to handle large data in python

Tags: python, xml, large-data

I'm reading an 50GB `XML` file (resulted from a `blastall` call) using the library `NCBIXML`

```
blasthandle = open( blastfile, 'r' )


blast_records = NCBIXML.parse( blasthandle )
for record in blast_records:
    get some infos from the record ...
```

reading the file is not that slow, but i want to perform some other things on the data (save it to text file, put it inside an array, ...)

what is the best python structure i can use to perform such tasks, currently i'm using normal arrays but it seems to be very slow and i'm not able to save the data into a text file because of memory problems

any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I've tried this

```
 blasthandle = open( blastfile, 'r' )
    for event, element in ET.iterparse(blasthandle):
        for child in element:
            print child.tag, child.text
    element.clear()
```

***EDIT 2***

Updating the libraries saved the problem, thanks to Martin

Comment: Use iterative parsing; either SAX or the `ElementTree.iterparse()` API (from the standard library or `lxml`). You'll need to give us more information on what you are trying to do to give you a proper answer.

Comment: Example answer: [How to extract information from ODP accurately?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16355498)

Comment: @MartijnPieters what i want to do is to just read some tags from each record in the file, and save them to a file for easy manipulation later.

Comment: I've tried the `etree.iterparser()` but i'm getting a segmentation fault error.

Comment: did you try to use grep to find the right tags and than just extract the bits between the tags you found? That way you can chop up the huge file into "workable" chunks ?

Comment: @usethedeathstar  i already know which tags i need, but the problem with `etree.iterparser()` is that it reads the full document tree inside the memory (at least thats what i've read on another question in SOF)

Comment: @ifreak: that sounds like one of the `lxml` dependencies (probably `libxml2`) is having trouble with something. Are you in a position to upgrade to the latest versions?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not in position to do this, but i can ask the system admin to do this for me.

Comment: `iterparse()` only builds the whole tree when you let it; delete the elements as you are done.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what i've tried is in my Edited question

Comment: @MartijnPieters Updating the libraries solved the problem, thank you very much.

Comment: @MartijnPieters actually not the update that solved the problem, i just tried the code in the EDIT without the tag parameter and it worked. When i put it again i get the same error, i don't know why?

Comment: @ifreak: your `element.clear()` is called *outside* the loop (it shoud be inside). No idea why a specific tag filter causes a segfault, I have not seen that before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39172/discussion-between-ifreak-and-martijn-pieters)